# Meaning of "We can never discount our way to Trillium's prices"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a statement in an old novel which says:

> We can never discount our way to Trillium's prices.

Here, Trillium is a mall and "We" are the people owning a shop.

I really didn't understand its meaning.

*Does it mean "We can't reduce our prices to that of Trillium's prices" **OR** "we can't give a discount which resembles with that of trillium"?*

Comment: apparently, you're right, but could you provide a fuller context of the sentence?

Comment: I think your first suggestion is better. On the basis of this sentence alone we don't that Trillium's prices are a result of a discount, all we know is the price that Trillum will charge is lower than the shop people can match by offering discounts.

Comment: I feel the sentence can be understood as: **We can never discount our way to the point where Trillium's prices are.** In other words, we can never make the prices of our products as low as Trillium's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a phrase  `to make your way to {a place}`.  It means to make efforts or to take action to reach the place. The "place" does not have to be an actual location; it can be a status of some kind.  And the verb **make**, which is very vague, can be replaced with other more specific verbs. For example:

> **Sleep** your way to the **top**.
>
> **Fight** your way to **freedom**.
>
> **Lie** your way to **political office**.
>
> **Crawl** your way to **daylight**.
>
> **Discount** your way to **Trillium's prices**.

That last one is a bit elliptical, since "Trillium's prices" is not immediately clear as a statement of "status" or "position". I imagine it would mean something like "to the point where you are able to compete with Trillium on price".